# Building a simple qt project with CMake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I'm trying to build a simple qt project with CMake, which contains **main.cxx**, **MainWindow.cxx** and **MainWindow.hxx**. When I try to make install it says **fatal error: 'QMainWindow' file not found**, but I do added Widgets in the **CMakelists.txt**.
Here are the codes:
**main.cxx:**

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "MainWindow.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
        QApplication GUI(argc, argv);
        MainWindow window;
        window.shou();

        return GUI.exec();
}
```

**MainWindow.cxx**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) 
     : QMainWindow(parent)
{

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}
```

MainWindow.hxx

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_HXX_
#define MAINWINDOW_HXX_

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT

public:
      MainWindow(QWidget *parent =0);
      ~MainWindow();
};

#endif
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3 FATAL_ERROR)
project(Gui_Window)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)


find_package(Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)


add_library(MAINWINDOW ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/MainWindow.cxx)

add_executable(Gui_Window ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/app/main.cxx)

target_link_libraries(Gui_Window PUBLIC Qt6::Widgets
                                        MAINWINDOW
                     )

install(TARGETS Gui_Window DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

What should be the problem?

Comment: The problem is that you're using a QtWidgets header in your MAINWINDOW library but your library does not link against Qt6::Widgets and therefore the Qt6::Widgets include directory is not added to the compilation of MAINWINDOW --> MAINWINDOW must link against Qt6::Widgets when you want to use Qt6::Widgets in there.

Comment: Oh, yes you're right, I changed it as link Widgets to MAINWINDOW then link MAINWINDOW to the executable, but another error occurred of main.cxx: 'MainWindow.hxx' file not found. (I fixed the typo of .h to .hxx in main.cxx)

Comment: Because your Gui_Window target does not know where to search the header - you forgot either target_include_directories(Gui_Window ...) or better target_include_directories(MAINWINDOW  PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src) so cmake adds the include path automatically to the target which links against MAINWINDOW.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your MainWindow.cxx file should be included in your CMakeLists.txt file like this:

```
set(PROJECT_SOURCES MainWindow.cxx)
```

You'd want main in there too.

As an aside, it's much easier to use Qt Creator and let it generate the CMakeLists.txt file for you.

Comment: What should be the problem if I add my source files in a library then link it to the executable file (just like what I did)? I used this method before for another project (no qt) it seems work fine...

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that approach, but...that's not what your CMakeLists.txt file is trying to do. If you want to create a library (the reasons for which I can't understand), you need to explicitly do that, *then* include the library in your build. Cmake isn't a mind-reader; it can't know that you want to convert that cxx file into a library first, so it's trying to use a source file as a library, and general hilarity ensues.

Comment: Sorry I'm really a noob of cmake (Maybe also English), do you mean the method I adding that source file to a library is wrong? What's the correct way to do that..?

Comment: I hesitate to comment further, as I'm not a Cmake expert myself, but...the add_library() command is expecting an (already-built) library as input. You're supplying a C++ source file. That's not going to work. May I ask why you're trying to do this? That library isn't going to be reusable by other Qt programs anyway, unless you do a lot of extra work.

Comment: The reason I do so is because in the CMake Tutorial step2: adding a library, it taught me to add source files to a library then link it to the executable file. Of course I only have one source file, but when I have 100 source files it will be useful to add a library. I mean, I just want to use a more general way to write CMakeLists.

Comment: Can you link that tutorial? I'd like to see it.

Comment: It's here: 
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/guide/tutorial/Adding%20a%20Library.html

Comment: Very interesting...it looks like my earlier statement might have been wrong. I probably should stop giving advice at this point; hopefully someone with more cmake knowledge can answer. I hope I didn't lead you astray. As a parting comment, I do notice the example in the tutorial uses a subdirectory for the library; I wonder if doing the same would help you.

Comment: Yes, it's solved that I should link the qt lib into my source file first cuz I'm using qt functions (see the comment below the question), but thank you anyway!